# my global configuration looks wrong

Tags: global-configuration

I accidentally turned on "yes" to a debug language option in my global configuration page and I think it screwed up my admin page, see attached image:

[image: omage shows my global configuration page]

How do I get back to my default view?

Comment: @irata's answer is good (Except the "Save" button will probably say "JTOOLBAR_APPLY"). I'm just adding in an explanation of what you did, so you better understand what you're seeing. Joomla keeps translated strings keyed to a constant, so changing languages is as simple as installing a new file of translated strings for the keys. When you switch on "Debug Language" and it's set to show "Constant" instead of "Value" those keys will be shown, untranslated. It's intended to help you see which key is being shown so you can track a translation problem.

Comment: Hi Arlen, it was all good "JTOOLBAR_APPLY" didn't show up. Thank you for letting me know what the "Debug Language" is used for. Have an excellent 2020.

Comment: Do future visitors a favor, then and please accept @irata's answer as correct. That way when someone else runs into that problem they'll find it quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the `**mod_quickicon_global_configuration**` and that should take you to the Global Configuration where you can select the second tab across, `**COM_CONFIG_SYSTEM**`, and then change the second field under `**COM_CONFIG_DEBUG_SETTINGS**` change to `**JNO**` and then click Save.

Or you can edit your configuration.php for your site and change

```
public $debug_lang = '1';
```

to

```
public $debug_lang = '0';
```

Comment: Hi Irata, thank you, thank you..it worked! Have a brilliant 2020!

Comment: Can you please accept the answer as resolving your issue so it will show as complete, thank you.